# QTMovie delegate methods not being called

Tags: objective-c, macos, quicktime

Hey, I'm trying to trap the QTMovie progress delegate method calls, and the delegate methods don't seem to be getting called. I'm trying to trap the conversion progress event by implementing

**- (BOOL)movie:(QTMovie *)movie shouldContinueOperation:(NSString *)op withPhase:(QTMovieOperationPhase)phase atPercent:(NSNumber *)percent withAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes**

but the method is not getting called. I've looked at apples sample code here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/QTKitProgressTester/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003631 and can't seem to see very much difference between my code and their code. The file gets converted fine and shows up on my desktop and I can play it without issues. I just can't get the progress events. Any ideas? Here is my demo app that I'm using to test this with.

```
#import "testProjAppDelegate.h"
#import <QTKit/QTKit.h>
@implementation testProjAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    QTMovie* movie = [QTMovie movieWithFile:@"/Users/Morgan/Desktop/sample_iTunes.mov" error:nil];

    if (movie)
    {
        [movie setDelegate:self];

        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], QTMovieExport, 
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:kQTFileType3GPP], QTMovieExportType, nil];


        [movie writeToFile:@"/Users/Morgan/Desktop/test.mp4" withAttributes:dict error:nil];

        NSLog(@"DONE");
    }
}

- (BOOL)movie:(QTMovie *)movie shouldContinueOperation:(NSString *)op withPhase:(QTMovieOperationPhase)phase atPercent:(NSNumber *)percent withAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
{
    NSLog(@"PROGRESS");
    return YES; 
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is not working because my app was compiled for 64 bit. I'm assuming this is a bug in the QTKit framework? I found a few other mentions of QTMovie delegates not working in 64 bit applications. I can compile my app for 32 bit though which isn't a problem. Still, this should work in 64 bit, shouldn't it?